# Canvas - not drawing at correct position

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a canvas wrapped in dialog element and I have implemented a drawing app so I can draw something on canvas but it's not drawing on correct position of touch
Html

**Code Snippet**

```js
const ctx = c.getContext("2d")

const size = 5,
  Color = "red",
  cx = ((screen.width - c.width) / 2) - 25,
  cy = ((screen.height - c.height) / 2) - 25

console.log(cx, cy)

let sx = 0,
  sy = 0

c.ontouchstart = (e) => {
  const t = e.touches[0]
  sx = t.clientX - cx
  sy = t.clientY - cy
}

c.ontouchmove = (e) => {
  const t = e.touches[0]
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.moveTo(sx, sy)
  ctx.lineTo(t.clientX - cx, t.clientY - cy)
  ctx.lineWidth = size
  ctx.strokeStyle = Color
  ctx.lineCap = "round"
  ctx.stroke()
  sx = t.clientX - cx
  sy = t.clientY - cy
}
```

```css
#d {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<dialog id="d">
  <canvas width="200" height="200" id="c"></canvas>
  <button onclick="d.close()">close</button>
</dialog>
<button onclick="d.showModal()">Open</button>
```

Comment: When I try to log boundingclientrect.left pr top its 0

Answer (score 0):

Using d.getBoundingClientRect it works

Comment: You have to expand your answers, something like this will just get  you down votes